# Run testng.xml through a plugin

Tags: java, plugins, eclipse-plugin, testng, eclipse-rcp

I have made a plugin that can be imported in Eclipse. I want to give a button in my plugin behind which I want to run testng.xml present at a location such that it opens the console and starts it as a thread.
I want equivalent of what happens when we run a testng.xml in Eclipse:

[image: Testng Run through Eclipse]

This execution needs to be done through java code in plugin project so that console opens the same way and we can stop the thread if required.

Comment: What is your question? If you looking for the code of the TestNG Eclipse plug-in, it is here: https://github.com/cbeust/testng-eclipse/

Comment: @howlger no, I require a java code to execute the testng.xml from my own java plugin project such that it opens the console and starts running my thread of TestNG.

Comment: @AnuChawla - So where are you stuck ? What do you have as code so far ? Can you please help share that ?

Comment: @KrishnanMahadevan I want a java program to execute my testng.xml which in turns open the console(showing the thread running) as shown in the image. I want replica of "Right click on TestNG.xml>Run as>TestNG suite" as a java code.

Comment: Have you looked at the eclipse TestNG plugin code ? You should be able to get the relevant piece of code by looking at the codebase no ?